# Reading external Json file in Dart program - NO Flutter

Tags: json, dart

I am new to Dart.
it might be a really simple problem, but how is it possible to read a JSON file in a Dart project.
I can't find any solution on the internet.
I don't want to do it in a flutter, just with a simple Dart. This should be possible, or?

I have two files, one Dart file, and a JSON file, both in the same directory.
The Dart file should now open the JSON file and save it to a variable.
In python, the solution is really simple, but I found no way in dart.

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading a file and converting to json should be pretty straightforward:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  final file = File('file.json');
  final content = await file.readAsString();
  final instance = jsonDecode(content);

  // ... profit?
}
```

Comment: This could be working, but dart throws the error "Cannot open file". Must be the json file something special?
It's one folder with just two files inside, the same directory, what's wrong :(

Comment: Try a full path first (for example "D:\\files\\folder\\file.json"). If that works, try working out where your program is running and what the correct relative path to that position would be. The current directory is probably not the same directory as your dart source code file.